# Pass a variable from JavaScript to jsp array

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    video_count =0;
    videoPlayer = document.getElementById("ss");        
    video=document.getElementById("myVideo");

    function run() {
        video_count++;
        if (video_count == 3) video_count = 1;
        videoPlayer.setAttribute("src","<%=newdirectory+files[i]%>");     
        video.load();    
        video.play();
    }
</script>
```

Is that possible to pass the `video_count++` variable to jsp array file[i] in function `run()` ?? because all my video files are store in jsp array and I would like to use js `video_count++` to load the next video in my array.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different approach: loading all your videos on pageload (ajax and JSON), store them in a javascript array, and iterate through this array instead.